# Need to write PHP that creates an XML file, and PHP that reads that file. Which libraries / functions?

Tags: php, xml

I need to write PHP to export/import user data from one install of WordPress to another. I'd like to use XML. However, I'm not sure which libraries/functions would be best to use. Any advice? Thanks

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php

Comment: Please search a bit and read some manuals before asking a question. Especially as your question is very generic and obviously you're not the first person on earth with that problem ;) - Use SO for the more harder questions, like concrete problems.

Answer (score 0):

[SimpleXMLElement](http://php.net/manual/en/class.simplexmlelement.php) to start with.

Comment: Skimming through SimpleXML I'm not seeing much for creating the XML file, just reading it?

Comment: You don't have to create XML files. You can read, modify and access the needed data via SimpleXMLElement.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/book.xmlwriter.php if you want to write xml

Comment: @Cyrcle: Have you skimmed [*Example #10 Adding elements and attributes*](http://php.net/simplexml.examples-basic.php) ?

Comment: I just saw example #10. Time to do some playing and see if this will work for me.

Comment: try looking at DOMDocument if SimpleXMLElement isnt going to meet your needs. you should be able to just write your XML to a file with fwrite

Answer (score 0):

SimpleXML is geared toward reading XML. I'm going with DOM.